# Xamarin Forms Grid.Row Auto --> Still Shows Scrollbar in Grid Item

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, grid

I have a slight problem with XamarinForms, which I am fairly new with.

I do have a grid with several Items in it (ListView, Label, Stacklayout, Listview).
I thought setting RowDefinitions = "Auto" for each row, would make the whole Page scrollable.
But instead I have a scrollbar on each individual listView.

I have added a snippet of my code with one of the listViews inside.

How do I get the listViews shown in their full size and the scrollbar be for the whole page?
I have already tried a scrollview instead of the grid, but it did not work.

[Picture of Content in Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq619.png)

[Picture of Whole Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3GMP.png)

Xamarin Forms:

```
<Grid
    Padding="10"
    RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto"
    ColumnDefinitions="*"
    >
    
    <Label Padding="20" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="40" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Grid.Row="0"/>
    
    <ListView   ItemsSource="{Binding News}" 
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False"
                Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Padding="10">
                        <Label Text="{Binding DateTimeString}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Text}" MaxLines="4"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.Header>
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,Auto"
                            Padding="10"
                            VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="News" 
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                FontSize="32"/>
                <Label Text="mehr Anzeigen" 
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
            </Grid>
        </ListView.Header>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: ListView's are inherently scrollable.  If you want the entire list to display, you might be better off using a bindable StackLayout, which will not scroll.  And then wrap your entire page in a ScrollView to allow scrolling the page

Answer (score 0):

You can put the items in ScrollView which is capable of scrolling its content.
refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scrollview